# Why does my fixed header disappear in Safari 5?

Tags: html, css, safari, position, mobile-safari

I have a fixed header which works in IE, Firefox, Chrome and the latest Safari. In Safari 5 on iPad, the header disappears after it scrolls down to the target. Does anybody know why or have a fix?

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#top">Hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Section-1">Tjänster</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Section-2">Senast</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Section-3">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Section-4">Pris</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Section-5">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The basic CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

I've made an approximation of the problem [in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eJQyh/5/)

Comment: no. its working. you set your header background color as white(#FFFFFF). change your header styles .header {    position: fixed;    background-color: #000000;    width: 100%;}    http://jsfiddle.net/eJQyh/6/

Comment: Fixed position has always been a bit spotty on mobile browsers. Check http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Answer (score 0):

You are using white(`#FFFFFF`) in your header background. Thats the reason you can't see the fixed header. And then Don't forget to mention the `width` in your `.header`

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJQyh/7/)

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. After changing the colour, it still disappears in Safari 5. It doesn't matter that the background is white since the text isn't white.

Comment: Did you check specifically Safari 5 on iPad? It's working fine in Safari 7.